# What are layout transitions in graphics programming

Tags: vulkan

I'm following vulkan-tutorial.com and in the images portion of the tutorial it mentions layout transitions, but doesn't elaborate on what they are. I don't like to copy and paste code without knowing exactly what it does and I can't find a sufficient explanation in the tutorial or on google.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A "layout transition" is exactly what those words mean. It's when you transition the layout of an image sub-resource from one layout to another. So your question really seems to be... what is a layout?

In the Vulkan abstraction, images are composed of sub-resources. These represent distinct sections of an image which can be manipulated independently of other sections. For example, each mipmap level of a mipmapped image is a sub-resource.

At any particular time that an image sub-resource is being used by a GPU process, that sub-resource has a layout. This is part of the Vulkan abstraction of GPU operations, so exactly what it means to the GPU will vary from chip to chip.

The important part is this: layouts restrict how you can use an image sub-resource. Or more to the point, in order to use an image sub-resource in a particular way, it must be in a layout which *permits* that usage.

When a sub-resource is in the `VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_SHADER_READ_ONLY_OPTIMAL` layout, you can only perform operations which read from the sub-resource within a shader. The shader cannot write to the image, nor can the image be used as a render target.

Now, the general layout allows pretty much any use at any time while within that layout. However, this also can represent less optimal performance. Any of the more restricted layouts can make those accesses to the image more performance-friendly (depending on hardware).

So it is your job to keep track of the layout of any image sub-resources you plan to use. Now for most images, you're going to use destination transfer layout to upload to them, and then just leave them as shader read-only, because you don't generally use most images more arbitrarily. So generally, this means keeping track of render targets that you want to read from, as well as swapchain images (you have to transition them to the present layout before presenting them) and storage images.

Layout transitions typically happen as part of an explicit dependency between two operations. This makes sense; if you're uploading data to an image, and you later want to read from it, you need a dependency between the upload and the read. You may as well do the layout transition then, since the transition can modify the way the bytes of the image are stored, so you need the transfer to be done first.